# Show element of fundamental group is nontrivial

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm learning cohomology, and I'd like to show the following:

> Let $i:\mathbb RP^1\to\mathbb RP^n$ be the usual embedding taking $[x_0,x_1]\mapsto[x_0,x_1,0,\dots,0]$, where $n\ge2$. Further, let $v:S^1\to\mathbb RP^1$ be the fibration $(x_0,x_1)\mapsto[x_0,x_1]$. Show that $[i\circ v]$ is a nontrivial element of $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^n,*)$.

I tried proof by contradiction: Suppose $i\circ v$ is homotopic to the constant map $c$ which sends everything to $*$. Then these induce the same maps in cohomology: $v^*\circ i^*=(i\circ v)^*=c^*$. Recall that $H^q(\mathbb RP^m;\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ for all $0\le q\le m$. Let $\Omega_n\in H^1(\mathbb RP^n;\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ be the nonzero element, and similarly define $\Omega_1\in H^1(\mathbb RP^1;\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$. Then I already know that $i^*(\Omega_n)=\Omega_1$. The Gysin sequence shows that $v^*(\Omega_1)=0$.

I wanted to show that $c^*(\Omega_1)$ is nonzero. But I feel like I don't quite understand cohomology groups/rings enough. If we write $\Omega_n=\text{cls}~\omega_n$, where $\omega_n\in Z^1(\mathbb RP^n;2)$ is a homomorphism $C_1(\mathbb RP^n)\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, then the goal is to show that $$\omega_nc_\#:C_1(S^1)\to C_1(\mathbb RP^n)\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$$ is not a coboundary, but I haven't been able to do this. After all, isn't $\omega_nc_\#$ just the zero map?

This is Exercise 12.24 in Rotman, and includes the hint that $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^n,*)\cong\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb RP^1\approx S^1$. But I didn't use either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotman's claim is wrong.

We have $\mathbb RP^1 = S^1/\sim$, where $\sim$ identifies antipodal points. Then $v : S^1 \to \mathbb RP^1, v(x_0,x_1) = [x_0,x_1]$, is the quotient map.

Let $\mu_2 : S^1 \to S^1, \mu_2(z) = z^2$ (where $z$ is understood as a complex number with absolute value $1$). Clearly $
\mu_2(z) = \mu_2(z')$ if and onyl if $z = \pm z'$. Thus $\mu_2$ induces a homeomorphism $h : \mathbb RP^1 \to S^1$ such that $h \circ v = \mu_2$.

We conclude that $h_* : \pi_1(\mathbb RP^1) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ is an isomorphism of infinite cyclic groups.

The map $v$ repesents an element $[v] \in \pi_1(\mathbb RP^1)$. We have
$$h_*([v]) = [h \circ v] = [\mu_2] \in \pi_1(S^1)$$
which corresponds to the element $2 \in \mathbb Z$ under the isomorphism $\deg : \pi_1(S^1) \to \mathbb Z$. Hence also $[v]$ corresponds to $2$ under $\deg \circ h_*$. Let $g$ be the generator of $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^1)$ which corresponds to $1 \in \mathbb Z$ under $\deg \circ h_*$. Then $[v] = 2g$.

Now consider $i_* : \pi_1(\mathbb RP^1) \to \pi_1(\mathbb RP^n)$. We get
$$[i \circ v] = i_*([v]) = 2 i_*(g) = 0 \in \pi_1(\mathbb RP^n)$$
since $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^n) \approx \mathbb Z_2$.